# Errors in a brand new scene with no c#? (NullReferenceException:)

Tags: unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I have just (re)installed Unity version 2017.3.1f1 and I am literally just opening a blank scene, with no `.cs` but getting an error when I 'Create Empty' in the Hierarchy?

It does create the new GameObject (which is highlighted in blue) in the hierarchy but it is unclickable and I can't click the Main Camera or Directional Light either and I get this error:

I actually tested in Unity 2017.3.0f3 and get exactly the same issue.

---

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEditor.TooltipView.Close () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/TooltipView/TooltipView.cs:98)
UnityEditor.RenameOverlay.RemoveMessage () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/RenameOverlay.cs:335)
UnityEditor.RenameOverlay.EndRename (Boolean acceptChanges) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/RenameOverlay.cs:111)
UnityEditor.IMGUI.Controls.TreeViewController.EndNameEditing (Boolean acceptChanges) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/TreeView/TreeViewController.cs:811)
UnityEditor.SceneHierarchyWindow.OnLostFocus () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/SceneHierarchyWindow.cs:409)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:222)
Rethrow as TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:232)
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MethodBase.cs:115)
UnityEditor.HostView.Invoke (System.String methodName, System.Object obj) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/HostView.cs:295)
UnityEditor.HostView.Invoke (System.String methodName) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/HostView.cs:288)
UnityEditor.HostView.OnLostFocus () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/HostView.cs:135)
```

---

Screenshot: 
[image: This is an image of my Unity window]

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Sounds like something you should report to them.

Comment: Thanks Eddge! I am no expert at all but it does seem like a 'bug' rather than something I've done!? Ta

Comment: If this is a clean install, and this error is appearing in a new project, in a new scene that it is definitely a bug.  I have never seen it before, so it could be some type of comparability problem.

Comment: The only thing I can think is a client is working in Plastic Gluon which they asked me to install - I've just removed the program as they are moving to Perforce next week. I'll see if that makes a difference...

Comment: Didn't make any difference - sending Bug Report to Unity as we speak - thanks!!

Comment: If re-install didn't work, have tried updating your graphics card driver? Sometimes, gc driver update solves Unity issues.

Comment: Thanks Programmer, I'll try that.

Comment: Darnit! I updated my Radeon AMD driver and restarted etc and it's still the same. Aarrrrgh!

Comment: Reverting the Editor to Factory/original settings solved this issue.
(found a similar issue posted in Unity Forums)